# Could not set tab bar image in Xcode 4.2 Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2, tabbar

I created new tab bar project in xcode 4.2 and there is no app delegate xib file. Project has two navigation controller. I can set name of tab bar but couldn't set image. I am completely fed up with many tries. `FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]`

```
firstView.title=@"Birthdays";
firstView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomleft.png"]; 
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil]; 
secondView.title=@"Settings"; 
secondView.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomright.png"]; 
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondView];
    navController2.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    [viewControllers addObject:navController2];
```

[image]

Here you can see what sort of output I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell from the code you posted, but you probably want to set the image on the `tabBarItem` of the `UINavigationController` (`navController2`), since it looks like that is what you directly add to you `UITabBarController`:

```
navController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomright.png"];
```

The reason you can set the title is that navigation controllers by default automatically have the title of their current child view controller.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you successfully replaced the left image, however it has no transparent areas. Did you follow the guidelines for designing the tab icon?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

You need to use a white image on transparent background. If your background is not transparent, the whole image will just be a blue box, like the one on your left tab.

Example: To make a tab with a star on it, draw a completely white star on a transparent background. Do not use any other colors than completely white and transparent black.

Comment: This is your problem.  I've found a pretty straight-forward tutorial here: http://greenerpastures.dk/blog/iphone-udvikling/how-to-make-tab-bar-icons

Answer (score 0):

You never need to do this:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomleft2x.png"];
```

`UIImage` will automatically determine whether the `@2x` is needed or not based on the screen scale, so make it simply:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomleft.png"];
```

Unless, of course, your resource name is actually `bottomleft2x@2x.png`

Comment: Coneybeare, I did also same thing but still getting same result. You can see image in my answer.

Comment: Sometimes xcode fail adding files to the project, maybe you need delete manually and add again to the xcode

Answer (score 0):

dude tab bar only allows white color and transparent background so if u want the picture to be like a birthday cake then draw a white birthday cake on a transparent background then add some transparent pixel in side the cake to create the looks of a cake instead of just the outline of the cake then u can set yr image to tab bar