# Add image on tabbar programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

How to add images on tab bar programmatically in iOS (Xcode 4.2)?

I already asked question but did not get a satisfied answer at [Could not set tab bar image in Xcode 4.2 Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385234/could-not-set-tabbar-image-in-xocde-4-2-programmatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[UITabBarItem tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
    [tabItem setTitle:@"theTitle"];
    [tabItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 5 Appearance api,

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

also see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800474/custom-uitabbar-background-image-not-working-in-ios-5),  second highest voted answer explains both cases <5.0 and =>5.0 case.

Answer (score 0):

Write this method in your ViewController:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    }
    return self;
}
```