# How to add clients logo on Tab Bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, tabbar

in my iPad Application, **how to add an image of clients logo in the bottom Right Corner?**
My application contains 5 tabs.
I am working for iOS 4.3.

Comment: your question needs a bit more detail:  do you want this logo to be part of the tab bar controller and actually *do* something when it's touched, like all the other tabs do?

Comment: no i just want to add it like a static image. :)

Comment: **Hope this link will cheer you!!!** [Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392165/add-image-on-tabbar-programatically-in-xcode-4-2

Comment: @ArunKumarTiwari Link in comments: `[link](http://example.com)` ==> [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *navBarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/menubar.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImage
                               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *barButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/barbutton.png"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage:barButton
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/back.png"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:backButton
                                              forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/tabbar.png"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images/selection-tab.png"]];
```

more you can find here
http://alexyoung.org/2011/12/07/ios-5-redemption/

or google for UIAppearance

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the tab bar in such that, there is room for your UIImageView.

Add your UIImageView as a subview UITabBarcontroller.view and position it.

use the following code to set the width of the UITabBarController

```
 for(UIView *view in tabBarController.view.subviews)
{


    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
    {
      view.frame = //set your rect
    }
 }
```

Comment: kindly tell me some more detail ,because i tried to add image in tabitem as subview but when i launch the app then it created an issue depends on the launch orientation (Lan/Por) as well as after rotating the view to landscape or portrait ? i have put the frame in shouldautorotate method so that it shifts it self when orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is have put a control over the UITabBar. Make this control have a UIButton for every tab, and then when connect these buttons to a method that programmatically calls the tab bar press, by using setSelected and the index for the pressed tab.

I think you can do better (less hacky) customizations with iOS 5 and up though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add a regular `UITabBarItem` and disable it:

```
[[tabBar items][4] setEnabled:NO];
```

The "4" is the 5th and last item in you tabBar. You can replace it by `tabBar.items.count-1` if you're not sure if you'll add any others in the future.

The static item will have a kind of watermark-effect because of it's disabled.

Comment: hmm well this watermark effect is not an appropriate solution for my problem , still thanks for the kind suggestion .
i will be grateful if any other suggestion you can provide. :)

Comment: Do you use a `UITabBarController`?

Comment: ya i have used self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;  in App Delegate.